Read Tables that are not tables in Excel File
I'm currently trying to read an Excel file with multiple tables but the tables are not saved as tables, they are saved just like information but divided into tables (don't know if that makes sense), I got to the point where I can read the Excel file but it reads the empty cells too which I'm not interested to, I just need to read the tables.
This is the code that I've written so far:
def separar_tablas(df): 
    tablas = [] 
    dfs = [] 
    tabla_actual = None

    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        for i, value in row.items():
            etiqueta = str(row[2])
    
            if pd.notnull(value):          
                if etiqueta.startswith('RuleTable'):
                    if pd.notnull(etiqueta):
                        tablas.append(etiqueta)
        
                        if tabla_actual is not None:
                            dfs.append(tabla_actual)
                    
                        tabla_actual = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
                    
                    tabla_actual = pd.concat([tabla_actual, row],axis = 1, ignore_index=True)
                    
        
    dfs.append(tabla_actual)
    return dfs


You should probably put a 'table' by worksheet starting at A1 and read the worksheet into a df with pd.read_excel.
Or if your table ranges never change you can use that to get only tables, but then you could also add sheet and make A1 = "the range of your table" and repeat for all tables

Thing is I can't change the file since it is used to run some rules on a different system, and the range of the tables do change from one to another.

pandas expects that one page (worksheet) has only one table - so you have to work on your own.

So do you have a way to identify begin and end of your tables ? I see your are checking if it starts with 'RuleTable' ?
etiqueta = str(row[2]) will never change in your second loop you can define it above too. If you have an example of file or some extra informations it would be easier to help you

Yeah, each table starts bv 'RuleTable" and it ends when there no more cells with information, then there is a certain number of empty cells (it changes) and another table starts with the same 'RuleTable'

@PanagiotisKanavos Yea but he said his tables are not in an ExcelTable or Range so it's not possible :-( When the data is bad from the start it makes everything so complex...

@JoachimHuet Excel has named ranges and tables. You can use the range or table name as part of a range address, the same way you use eg $A1:$D4. Unfortunately read_excel can't handle named ranges, although openpyxl itself supports them

@CarlosFf Okay, and can you have several table in the horizontal direction ?
Per row there will only be one table at a time ?

Corrrect, multiple tables in the horizontal direction and just one table at a time. Once another 'RuleTable' is found it means a new Table Rule is starting with different parameters than the previous one.

@CarlosFf you can't do what you want with read_excel alone. It doesn't even allow ranges, only a list of columns. There are several duplicate questions in fact. You can use openpyxl directly to read a table's contents and insert them into a dataframe though, something shown in most of the duplicates

What you can do is going with two passes.

Get the coordinates of cells where a table starts
Loops through theses coordinates to bulk-read the table

!WARNING NOTE!: If one of your table contains an empty cell you will have to tweak the code to define the size of the table before reading it cell by cell or it might cut the table.
I only tested this code with a single excel file, you should tell me if something is not going right.
import pandas as pd

# read your file
df = pd.read_excel('data/test.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')

# First pass: get table start coordinates
table_starts_coordinates = []
for rowId, row in df.iterrows():
    for colId, value in row.items():
        if str(value).startswith('RuleTable'):
            table_starts_coordinates.append((rowId, str(colId).replace('Unnamed: ', '')))

tables = []
for row_id, col_id in table_starts_coordinates:
    # Iterate upwards until a blank cell is encountered
    r: int = int(row_id)
    c: int = int(col_id)
    i = 0
    table_data = []
    # Iterate through the DataFrame starting from the table start coordinates
    # until a blank cell is encountered on both direction.
    for _, row in df.iloc[r:].iterrows():
        j = 0
        if pd.isnull(row[c]):
            break
        for _, cell in row[c:].items():
            if pd.isnull(cell):
                break
            table_data.append((cell, i, j))
            j += 1
        i += 1
    
    # Create a DataFrame from the table data
    # table_data[-1] contains the last cell coordinates so i use it to define the shape of the DataFrame
    # if your table contains empty cells you should do one pass on the first row to get the number of columns
    # and then one pass on the first column to get the number of rows and then read the data (what I do above)
    table_df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(table_data[-1][1]), columns=range(table_data[-1][2]))
    for val, i, j in table_data:
        table_df.loc[i, j] = val

    tables.append(table_df)


read_excel doesn't support ranges or names. You'll have to use openpyxl to read a range's or table's values and create a DataFrame from them. For example, the following code:
path=r"c:\projects\Spikes\Book1.xlsx"

wb=load_workbook(filename=path)
ws=wb['Sheet1']
table=ws.tables["Table1"]
rng=ws[table.ref]

data_rows=[]
for row in rng:
    data_rows.append([cell.value for cell in row])

print(table.ref)
pd.DataFrame(data_rows[1:], columns=data_rows[0])

Given a sheet with a table named Table1:

Prints
>>> print(table.ref)
D6:F9
>>> pd.DataFrame(data_rows[1:], columns=data_rows[0])
    A  B       C
0   1  5  Banana
1   2  6  Potato
2  34  8  Tomato


Can't use .tables because the tables aren't saved as tables.

@CarlosFf your question asked about tables though. Painted cells aren't tables. In any case, the logic is the same. Find the range, copy the values and create a DataFrame from them

@CarlosFf how frequently do you have to read such files? You could find the ranges yourself and possibly name them, instead of trying to write code that finds where they start and end.

Yeah, the question said it but the explanation of the problem I made it clear that the tables were not tables, I edited the question though in case somebody is going through the same problem.
It's a file that has a set of rules that are later ran in a different system, I need the code to test the updates of the rules before being upload to the system so we can make sure everything is working before releasing the changes.
